# Как сделать первую букву каждого слова заглавной? (регулярные выражения JS)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, который исправляет первую букву каждого слова в инпуте на заглавную букву, очень полезно для инпутов имен. Так вот данный код исправляет только англоязычные имена, как исправить регулярное выражение чтобы он исправлял и русские имена.

```js
function capitalize(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/gi, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<label><span class="label_red">*</span> Имя, Фамилия:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Иван Иванов" required onkeyup="capitalize(this);">
```

Я пробовал написать `/\b[а-я](?=[а-я]{2})/gi` но это не работает.
Если ввести имя `anna ivanova` оно исправится на `Anna Ivanova`. Как сделать тоже самое для кириллицы и добавить регулярное выражение для русских имен. `анна иванова` => `Анна Иванова`. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Просто добавьте в регулярное выражение "а-я", должно сработать.

Comment: В самом-то регулярном выражении у тебя задано только для английских букв. Расширь это ```/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/gi```

Comment: Я пробовал написать `/\b[а-я](?=[а-я]{2})/gi` но это не работает

Comment: Не работает, потому \b - распознает границы слов только латиницы. Можно изменить регулярку и вместо \b указать список символов, которые означают начало слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Новое слово... это либо начало строки `^`, либо буква после пробела, так? Ну вот пример:

```js
let str = 'you know nothing jon snow'; 
   // Просто пробел ↓ хотя можно было явно записать \s ('s', от слова 'space')
str = str.replace(/( |^)[а-яёa-z]/g, function(x){ return x.toUpperCase(); }  );

console.log( str );
```

И в вашем случае:

```js
function capitalize(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/( |^)[а-яёa-z]/g, function(u){ return u.toUpperCase(); }  );
}

document.getElementById('bubu').addEventListener('input', function(){
  capitalize(this);
});
```

```html
<label><span class="label_red">*</span> Имя, Фамилия:</label>
<input id="bubu" type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Иван Иванов" required>
```

P.s. хотя можно было без регулярок, разбить строчку на `str.split(' ')` элементы массива... в каждом элементе сделать первую букву заглавной (уже независимо от языка), а потом собрать строчку обратно.

P.P.s `input` срабатывает только в случае изменения введенного текста, тогда как `keyup` запускается после каждой нажатой кнопки, даже CTRL, SHIFT и т.п. Поэтому можно использовать первое, чтобы лишний раз не запускать функцию.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Ты про `ё` забыл :(

Comment: Упсь. Добавлен)

Comment: Перемудрил. Можно же просто в скобки: `[a-zа-яё]`.

Comment: Кстати, `( |^)[а-яёa-z]` :)

Answer (score 2):

Если поддерживается достаточно новый стандарт джаваскрипта, то можно так:

```js
function capittalize(s) {
  return s.toLowerCase().replace(/(?<!\p{Lowercase})\p{Lowercase}/gu, ch => ch.toUpperCase())
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.querySelector("output").textContent = capittalize(e.target.value)
})

document.querySelector("input").dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

```html
<input value="ёЖиК ЛеснИчий">
<output></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно передавать callback в качестве параметра для `replace`

```js
var input = "Example string пример строки"

console.log(
  input.replace(/[a-zа-я]+/gi, (match) => match[0].toUpperCase()+match.substr(1))
)
```

Comment: Прикольно) Тогда можно всю регулярку заменить на `\S+` и не заморачиваться...

Comment: Тоже про `ё` забыл.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не использовал строго указанные диапазоны символов, т.к. они строго привязаны к используемому/возможному набору символов. Вместо этого, как уже говорил @OPTIMUSPRIME, можно ориентироваться на другие ориентиры:

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) {
            return a.toUpperCase();
        });
};
'your string'.capitalize(); // -> 'Your String'
'бабушка курит трубку'.capitalize();  // -> 'Бабушка Курит Трубку'
'località àtilacol'.capitalize()      // -> 'Località Àtilacol'
```

Преимущество этого подхода - в его универсальности, т.е. он будет работать вне зависимости от используемых символов в строке.

Для нормализации строки, как предлагает [автор](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489553/disfated) оригинального [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592235/3129992), можно дополнить:

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function(lower) {
    return (lower ? this.toLowerCase() : this)
        .replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { 
            return a.toUpperCase();
        });
};
'javaSCrIPT'.capitalize();      // -> 'JavaSCrIPT'
'javaSCrIPT'.capitalize(true);  // -> 'Javascript'
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811